# Do iPad apps work on iPad PRO and vice-versa?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications

I would like to know if an app made for iPad only will work on the iPad Pro?
Also, will the app be properly scaled?

Is it possible for an app made for iPad pro to work on an regular iPad?

If yes will it be properly scaled?

Comment: Which specific apps do you have in mind here?

Comment: Basically all the apps that are on the app store for the iPad. I am the currently existent ones. It seems they all should work... at least if AutoLayout is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how the app was made.

Apps are meant to define the position of interface components in terms of their distance from the edges of the screen by using a technology called AutoLayout (included in Xcode, the development environment for Apple devices).

If the app was made with AutoLayout then yes, it will scale.

As for whether or not they will work, iPhone and iPod apps can already be used on iPad so there should be no reason for which iPad apps shouldn't work on the Pro.

However, when the interface contains a lot of stuff and the interface was designed for a bigger screen, the components could get squashed together. If particular technologies are required (e.g. Apple Pencil) they won't work on the regular iPads.